# Unpredictable output

Tags: jakarta-ee

```
     protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

       out.println("<html>");

       out.println("<head></head>");
       out.println("<body>");
       String err[]=(String[]) request.getAttribute("error");

       *
```

> The error array of Strings is sent from the next page and received in
>   this one.However 
>              if I try to place the for loop with the same code as given below here at this place
>              then there is no display even of the form fields I can't understand why
>          I am using Netbeans Ide and the name of the servlets are:-form,addLeague nad success

*

```
       out.println("<form action=addLeague method=post>");
       out.println("name:  <input type='text' name='name'>");
       out.println("Season: <input type='text' name='season'>");
       out.println("year <input type='text' name='year'>");
       out.println("submit:<input type='submit' value='save'>");
       out.println("</form>");
        for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
       {
           if(err[i]!=null)
               out.println("<h1>"+err[i]+"</h1>");
       }
       out.println("</body>");
       out.println("</html>");



    } 

    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }


    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This page shows the code of the form servlet to which control returns from the addLeague servlet if there is some error in filling up the form details.The error generally are of blank fields or Number Formats

Comment: You could log something if there is an exception. Put that code inside the `catch(...) { }` part. If there is an exception in the loop, it would cause the form to disappear. Also look at the source of the HTML from your browser. You might find the `</body></html>` are missing anyway.

Comment: Thanx it the work fine with just a minor modification to your idea.I put the remaining contents in the finally block so that I could have the check being performed always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be better but be warned that catching `Exception` is pretty much guaranteed to cause you more pain than it is worth. You should just catch exceptions that are actually occurring.

If you are getting, for example `NullPointerException` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, then add some code to keep it form happening. In your case, this would mean changing the `i<=3` to `i <= err.length` for the latter.

If you need to catch some condition, catch a specific exception, For example, `NumberFormatException` or `ParseException` are common exceptions that need to be caught. Then you can give the parsed output some default value (say, 0 for a number) or show the user an error message.

```
try {
   out.println("<html>");
   out.println("<head></head>");
   out.println("<body>");

   String err[]=(String[]) request.getAttribute("error");
   try {
       for(int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
           if(err[i]!=null)
               out.println("<h1>"+err[i]+"</h1>");
       }
   } catch (Exception e) { // This is a bad idea. Use a specific exception.
        e.printStackTrace();
   }

   out.println("<form action=addLeague method=post>");
   out.println("name:  <input type='text' name='name'>");
   out.println("Season: <input type='text' name='season'>");
   out.println("year <input type='text' name='year'>");
   out.println("submit:<input type='submit' value='save'>");
   out.println("</form>");
   out.println("</body>");
   out.println("</html>");
} catch(Exception e) { // Its a bad idea down here too
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {            
    out.close();
}
```